# Java Casting Error Using CFPOP

Tags: java, coldfusion

My CF9 application running on a windows server pops mail. When I attempt to retrieve the entire body of the message, I sometimes get the following error...

```
Error:
An exception occurred while retrieving mail. 
The cause of this exception was: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.

Location:
Line 335 in controllers\Submissions.cfc
```

Not sure if this is pertinent, but FYI every message will have an image attached and the whole process ***usually*** works fine. This problem is intermittent.

### My Questions

1. Any idea what causes this?
2. Any idea how to catch and resolve this issue?

I suspect I'll need to drop down into java, but not sure where to start.

### Code Fragments

```
<cfscript>
// setup variables array for all cfpop calls
CFPopAttributes = {
    server = request.pop.server,
    port = request.pop.port,
    username = request.pop.username,
    password = request.pop.password,
    timeout = 300
    };
</cfscript>


<cfpop
    action="getall"
    name="entireEmail"
    uid="#uid#"
    attachmentpath="#originalsPath#"
    attributecollection="#CFPopAttributes#" // Line 335
    generateuniquefilenames="true"
    />
```

NOTE: I added the comment "Line 335" above to communicate exactly where in the code the template is breaking. If I move the attributecollection up or down (before/after other attributes), the error always breaks at the attributecollection line.

### Stack Trace

```
struct [Filtered - 1 of 8 keys hidden]

Detail: An exception occurred while invoking an event handler method from Application.cfc. The method name is: onRequest.
Message: Event handler exception.
RootCause:  
    [struct]
    Detail: The cause of this exception was: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.
    Message: An exception occurred while retrieving mail.
    RootCause:  
        [struct]
        Message: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
        StackTrace: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
            at coldfusion.mail.EmailTable.getAttachmentName(EmailTable.java:819)
            at coldfusion.mail.EmailTable.populate(EmailTable.java:283)
            at coldfusion.mail.PopImpl.getMails(PopImpl.java:241)
            at coldfusion.tagext.net.PopTag$1.run(PopTag.java:433)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at coldfusion.tagext.net.PopTag.doStartTag(PopTag.java:429)
            at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
            at cfSubmissions2ecfc1952269377$funcGETEMAIL.runFunction(D:\home\wwwroot\controllers\Submissions.cfc:335)
```

Comment: Have you tried not using the attributeCollection but just specifying each of the attributes individually?  OR pass all the attributes in through an attributeCollection structure?  It seems unlikely but I wonder if mixing some individual attributes and an attributeCollection  struct to the same tag might be causing some problems for CF

Comment: @duncan you make a good point. It seems unlikely, but unlikelier things have resolved issues before. Can't hurt to try.